# During a festival, what does "double growth rate for a year" imply?

Tags: kittens-game

In [Kittens Game](http://www.bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens), the hover text (using "Theme by Kida") for [festivals](http://www.bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=festival) looks like the following:

[image: Hold Festival hover text]

> Hold a cultural festival to make your kittens happy.  (+30% to happiness and double growth rate for a year)

The wiki page doesn't explain what "double growth rate for a year" means, and it's not clear what exactly can "grow" (it's certainly not kittens).

**Question**: During a festival, what does "double growth rate for a year" imply?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It refers to the time span between when you build a house and the time the kittens spawn in it.

Especially during endgame scenarios where you build a lot of houses quickly, it's nice to have them fill up faster. Some metaphysics upgrades also affect this behavior.